# How to launch Chrome in kiosk mode Linux/MacOS ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have this piece of code

```
public static void OpenBrowser(string url) {
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)) {
    WindowsBrowser.Launch(url); //My own code behind, works fine
} else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)) {
    Process.Start("xdg-open", url);
} else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX)) {
    Process.Start("open", url);
} else {
    // throw 
}
```

Windows part works just fine, launches Chrome in kiosk mode as desired. How can I do that for Linux and MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to point to the binaries to pass the appropriate command line arguments to the process.

For example, on Mac you could do this:

```
Process.Start("/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome", "--kiosk https://google.com");
```

I would think on Linux it would be something similar. Unfortunately this only works if there are no other windows open and only if the user has not renamed the app file.

Comment: I know that there must be no open windows. What can be done to avoid that issue?